# Increase the size of an array in c++ WITHOUT using a vector

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm working on an assignment for school and we need to dynamically increase the size of an array without using vectors.
This is what i have but it keeps clearing both lists.

```
string name;
int numOfClasses = 1;
string *listOfCourses = new string[numOfClasses];
string studentclasses;

void addToList(string n,int i) {
    numOfClasses++;
    string *copyOfListOfCourses = new string[numOfClasses];
    memcpy(copyOfListOfCourses, listOfCourses, numOfClasses + 1);

    copyOfListOfCourses[i] = n;
    delete[] listOfCourses;
    listOfCourses = copyOfListOfCourses;


}
```

Comment: You can't. Arrays in C++ are statically sized.

Comment: there has to be away or else we wouldn't have been given an assignment to do it

Comment: @EliSadoff Where doesr the OP uses _statically sized arrays_? Explain please?

Comment: Don't combine `memcpy` with C++ objects. This can (and will) lead to strange and most often wrong behavior.

Comment: Did your school also taught you that you can't use functions such as `memset` on non-POD types, such as `std::string`?  Or are they fixated into not teaching you C++ (i.e. you can't use std::vector)?

Comment: Every array declaration here is static.

Comment: its not that we can't use vectors in the future its that for this particular assignment we arent suppose to

Comment: @EliSadoff No, OP uses dynamic storage allocation and pointers, no arrays.

Comment: So `new String[numOfClasses]` is not an array?

Comment: Also note that the function parameter `int i` is unnecessary and potentially a bad idea (as an out-of-bounds index may be passed), and you are already keeping track of the size of your array (using `numOfClasses`)

Comment: @JjHagen -- `its not that we can't use vectors in the future` -- You should be using vectors now, not "in the future".  And second, the reason for the failure is that you're being taught `C` techniques that will not work (such as `memset`).  Don't shoot the messenger(s) here.

Comment: to expand on what @UnholySheep said, in this particular case using `memcpy` could lead to a use after free issue, because of the `delete[]` will call the destructors on the strings, meaning that any that have heap allocated their value will free that data. Your `memcpy`'d version will then try to access freed memory if you try to use or `delete[]` the new buffer.

Comment: The other issue is that if the strings are copy-on-write (like the ones in the older gcc compilers), calling `memcpy` wipes out the reference counting mechanism.  Honestly, `memcpy` shouldn't even be part of a beginner's C++ vocabulary at all.  Makes me wonder what really is being taught.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm thinking that's exactly what's happening here, if it was small string he'd probably seeing values 'randomly' disappear (the values that got put on the heap). But in this case he's seeing both lists clear, which makes me thing the refcount went to zero and it was already heap allocated. Either way it's undefined behavior, so nasal demons reign.

Comment: @EliSadoff: There's nothing "statically-sized" about the array pointed-to by that pointer. However, it's true to say that the array is not resizable.

Answer (score 6):

```
memcpy(copyOfListOfCourses, listOfCourses, numOfClasses + 1);
```

`memcpy()` is a C library function that knows nothing about C++ classes, their constructors or destructors. It cannot be used to copy an array containing `std::string`s. There are also at least two other problems with this `memcpy()`, besides the fact that it cannot be used with `std::string`s in the first place.

The correct way to do this is to use the C++ algorithm `std::copy`, or by using a manual `for` loop.

```
#include <algorithm>

std::copy(listOfCourses, listOfCourses+(numOfClasses-1),
          copyOfListOfCourses);
```

Note that `numOfClasses` at this point is the size of the new array, which is one greater than the size of the existing array, so the correct calculation must **subtract** 1 from numOfClasses, to get the size of the existing array, instead of adding 1.

Another problem is this:

```
copyOfListOfCourses[i] = n;
```

Instead of just copying the entire existing array to the new one, as is, what really then must happen is ***another*** copy to shift all values in the resized array, starting with the existing value at index #`i` up by 1, to make room for the new value. This is going to be a second `std::copy()` call, which you should be able to figure out by yourself, now.

Comment: if you want to be fancy you can use [`std::move_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator) so the strings are moved, not copied. Probably won't matter with small string optimization, but probably worth using.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new array, copy the old elements to the new array, and then replace the old array with the new array.  Obviously, using pointers.

Suppose that you have a pointer to an `int` array named `arr`,  created with dynamic memory:

```
int  *arr = new int[3];
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;
arr[2] = 3;
```

And you want to resize it, for example to store 4 elements.

You will create a pointer to a new `int` array named `temp` with the new size:

```
int *temp = new int[4];
```

Now copy the old elements to the new array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) // 3 for the size of the old array
{
    temp[i] = arr[i]; // copy the elements
}
```

Now you can delete the old memory and point `arr` to the new memory:

```
delete[] arr;
arr = temp;
```

And now you can do this:

```
arr[3] = 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that might be what you were looking for.
It creates a `temporary_array` with a size that is one unit bigger, copies the contents of the `my_array` into `temporary_array`. Then adds `input_value` to the end of the `temporary_array`, `delete[]`s my_array and assigns `my_array` to `temporary_array`. Finally it increments the `old_array_size` for future function calls.

```
int array_size = 1;
string *my_array = new string[array_size];

void add_to_array(string input_value, int &old_array_size) {

    int new_array_size = old_array_size + 1;

    string *temporary_array = new string[new_array_size];

    for(int i = 0; i < old_array_size; i++) {
        temporary_array[i] = my_array[i];
    }

    temporary_array[new_array_size - 1] = input_value;

    delete[] my_array;

    my_array = temporary_array;

    old_array_size++;

}
```

This might not be what one wants to do professionally, but it answers your question without using `std::vector`

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int *a;
int nCurrentSize =0;
void pushBack(int n)
{
  if(0 == nCurrentSize)
   {
    a= new int[1+nCurrentSize];
    a[nCurrentSize] = n;
   nCurrentSize++;
   }
   else
   {
     int *tmp = new int[nCurrentSize];
     memcpy(tmp,a,nCurrentSize*sizeof(int));
     delete []a;
     a= new int[1+nCurrentSize];
     memcpy(a,tmp,nCurrentSize*sizeof(int));
     a[nCurrentSize] = n;
     delete []tmp;
   nCurrentSize++;
    }
}
void display()
{
for(int i=0;i<nCurrentSize; i++)
  cout<<a[i]<<",";
}

int main()
{
pushBack(91);
pushBack(5);
pushBack(3);
pushBack(7);
pushBack(1);
pushBack(3);
pushBack(2);
pushBack(2);
pushBack(0);
pushBack(5); 

display();
cout<<endl<<nCurrentSize;
}
```

Comment: "Try this" without explanation is not very helpful.